# Как удалить весь текст после точки, если её может и не быть?

Tags: php

Каким образом можно удалить весь текст после точки, при этом оставив текст до точки? Следует учитывать, что в тексте точки может и не быть, тогда ничего обрезать не надо. Символы могут быть как и кириллическими, так и латинскими, используется utf8.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strstr.php

Comment: Точку нужно оставить? Или все равно?

Comment: @cheops да, нужно, но насколько я понял, если использовать функцию предложенную Mike, то получится как-то так: $var = strstr($var, '.', true); $var = $var.'.';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str="тестовая строка";
$a=mb_strstr($str,".",true);
if($a) $str=$a.".";
print $str;
```

Вариант немного быстрее, чем использование регулярных выражений

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом, если нужно сохранить точку

```
<?php
$text = 'до точки.после точки';
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\.).*$/u', '', $text);
```

и таким образом, если она не нужна

```
<?php
$text = 'до точки.после точки';
echo preg_replace('/\..+$/u', '', $text);
```

Comment: `(?<=\.).*$` требует 13 шагов КА регулярок для строки "123.456". плюс 2 шага на каждый символ. Аналогичное `\.\K.*$` - только 5 шагов, т.к. просто бежит по строке, ищет точку, перешагивает ее и берет все до конца строки, backtracking исключен

Comment: Принято, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу ещё один вариант:

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit.';

$str = explode( '.', $str )[0];

echo $str;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83113a892cd76b51359a280630890e247c851b88